# Insert new user AspNetUser from another controller in .NET 7

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using .NET 7 and I saw some posts about the questions I look for, but no one similar my error and my way to insert the new user inside the `AspNetUser` table. I have my company controller and I try insert some fields inside the `AspNetUser`, but the away I get errors. I am showing my controller code - if someone can help I really appreciate.

This is my controller

```
public class CompanyController : Controller
{
     private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
     private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
    
     private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
     private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _webHostEnvironment;

     public CompanyController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment)
     {
         _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
         _webHostEnvironment = webHostEnvironment;
     }

     [HttpPost]
     [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
     public IActionResult Create(Company company, IFormFile? file)
     {
         if (ModelState.IsValid)
         {
             var user = new ApplicationUser
                            {
                                Email = company.CompanyEmail,
                                PasswordHash = company.CompanyPassword,
                            };

             var result = _userManager.CreateAsync(user, company.CompanyPassword).ConfigureAwait(false);

             string wwwRootPath = _webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath;

             if (file != null)
             {
                 string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
                 string companyPath = Path.Combine(wwwRootPath, @"images\company");

                 using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(companyPath, fileName), FileMode.Create))
                 {
                     file.CopyTo(fileStream);
                 }

                 company.CompanyLogo = @"\images\company\" + fileName;
             }

             _unitOfWork.Company.Add(company);
             _unitOfWork.Save();

             TempData["success"] = "Company created successfully.";

             return RedirectToPage("/Account/Login", new { area = "Identity" });
         }

         return View(company);
    }
}
```

In the result, the `_usermanager` returns null.

Comment: Hi @Pe Zar, be sure dependency injection the UserManager by constructor. Besides, could you pls share your Program.cs  for how do you register the identity services?

Answer (score 0):

From looking at our code the only thing I can think of is you are missing the initialization of user manager and sign manager in your company controller constructor. And that's why it's getting null. You are using dependency injection then you need to inject all things which you want in constructor like this

```
public CompanyController(
    UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
    SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
    IUnitOfWork unitOfWork,
    IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment)
{
    _userManager = userManager;
    _signInManager = signInManager;
    _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    _webHostEnvironment = webHostEnvironment;
}
```

If you still get user manager null then check your startup.cs or progam.cs files and see you have done proper configuration of asp.net core identity like below.

```
var connectionString = 
builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
  options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => 
   options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
  .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

You can find more info here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: It should be `builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>`.

Comment: HI Jalpesh, if I do like you suggest I lost my Login Page (identity), so I change like you said but when I run the page the login page come a error.

Comment: If i make this change I don't have access on the Login Page, this is because my Login Page it is the first access, sow when I run the project my first page it is the Login Page, and the Login Page it is from Identity.

Comment: You need to put tag  [AllowAnonymous] tag on the login page action method

Answer (score 0):

Hey can you add the error log or screenshot of error page you get.
there can be multiple reason for error to occur. error log will help to understand the error.

according to my knowledge I think this will help:

```
var user = new IdentityUser { UserName = company.CompanyEmail, Email = company.CompanyEmail };
var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, company.CompanyPassword);
```

Do not add passwordhash to the use it take care of that itself, but username and email are required as they will be used in login and identifying the user.

Note : email used in User Object will be used in while logging the user

Comment: Hi Sahil, so now i have another error come true, so I fowling like Jalpesh post but now i have this error : InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[SysComm.Models.ApplicationUser]' while attempting to activate 'SysComm.Areas.Admin.Controllers.CompanyController'. End if I try change in my Program.cs like him suggest I lost my Login Page because i use the login page from identity.

Comment: ` builder.Services
    .AddIdentity<IdentityUser,IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = $"/Identity/Account/Login";
    options.LogoutPath = $"/Identity/Account/Logout";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = $"/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
});

builder.Services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages(); `

Comment: Hi @PeZar, it should be `builder.Services.AddIdentity<AppllicationUser,IdentityRole>()`.

Comment: Hi Rena, i try to do like you show me but because I use my login page with default page, my constructor is `builder.Service.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()` , if I change this to : `builder.Service.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()`, I lost the default login page. Any solution for this case? Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Hi guys, I managed to find the error, and what is the reason for injection error. In addition to following all the steps given here, the data injection method within _LoginPartial.cshtml must be changed as well. Thank you very much to everyone who helped me.  So in the _LoginPartial you need change `@inject SignInManager<Identity> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<Identity> UserManager` to `@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager`